# Using "set /p" in C++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I'm trying to set a windows command line environment variable (to help automate starting a windows process requiring user input) and then echo it back via system().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("set /p foo= foo=");
    system("echo %foo%");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Upon running, I receive this feedback:

> foo=bar
>
> %foo%
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

For the program to work, I need to receive "bar", the content of %foo%, but this is not happening.

What is strange is that the code works if inputted directly into the command line.

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe>set /p foo= foo=
foo=bar

C:\Users\JohnDoe>echo %foo%
bar
```

Why does the C++ code not work?

EDIT:

Using the suggested change, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("set /p foo=\" Enter foo= \" & echo %foo%");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Returns this feedback:

> Enter foo= bar
>
> %foo%
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Using the following code works, but opens a second window:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("set /p foo=\" Enter foo= \" & start echo %foo%");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> Enter foo= bar
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Then in the second window:

> bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system` runs a new instance of the command interpreter. Setting environment variables in that process has no effect on the program's own process. And unfortunately the C++ standard library has very limited support for environment variables: just a function `getenv`.

For your purposes, in Windows you might instead issue a call like `system( "set foo=bar & run_that_program" );`.

Comment: Tested your suggestion, more information added to question.

Comment: That doesn't work because command-line expansion of environment variables (`%foo%`) happens immediately, *before* the `set` command runs.  Alf's version, where you run another program, will work - the `run_that_program` process will see the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable directly in your C program, using the [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx) function.  (And of course you can prompt the user for the value to set using the usual C I/O functions.)

Such a variable should be inherited by programs you start with system().